# Package csvsimple: How do I reject the last line of a csv file

Tags: beamer, csv, csvsimple

Ultimately I want to read a csv (comma separated variable) file into LaTeX and display a table. I'm doing this within the `beamer` document class. I'm currently using the `\csvautobooktabular` command from `csvsimple` to do this, and I've just about got it to work. However I need to exclude the last line and the csv files I'm reading can be an arbitrary length. So I was wondering how I could use `\csvfilterreject` to eliminate the last line. Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\csvautobooktabular[respect all]{test.csv}
\end{document}
```

It works with the file `test.csv`:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
```

If this isn't possible using `csvsimple`, could someone provide me with an example using a different package?

---

I tried the example in the now accepted answer and I received compilation error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
```

It appears I must use XeTeX or LuaTeX to compile this. Is there a way I can avoid this? I'm currently using pdflatex for compiling my documents, and I'm very weary of making such a change.

Comment: That can't be with my code. I compiles it with pdflatex without no problems. my version is: `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) `. Have you compiled my given code without any changes? If yes, your system has a problem, update it. If not, please compile my without changes. It compiles with only one warning (okay, comming from `filecontents`). Or used you `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`?

Comment: You're quite right. I'm not sure why this wasn't working for me yesterday, but it works now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\csvautobooktabular[respect all]{\jobname.csv}

\csvreader[%
  autotabular,
  before filter=\ifthenelse{\equal{\csvcoli}{9}}{\csvfilterreject}{\csvfilteraccept}
]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}%

\end{document}
```

See page 12 of the documentation.  There is the code you only have to change for the if then else condition.

```
\csvreader[%
      autotabular,
      before filter=\ifthenelse{\equal{\csvcoli}{9}}{\csvfilterreject}{\csvfilteraccept}
    ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}%
```

means that if in row 1 (`\csvcoli`) is a `9`, then command `\csvfilterreject` is executed, which ends all further operations. If not, reading goes on.